# java.sql.Exception: No Suitable Driver Found for jdbc:sqlserver... using integrated security

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've read various posts but have not been able to get my java connection to SQL Server 2014 Express to work:

It seems like the code is not able to find the driver.

I placed the file `mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar` in the applications build folders. 
I tried various options about adding the CLASSPATH, without success, but it seems that this is not necessary for the recent versions of the driver.

I'm NOT using an IDE

```
            //===================================================================== 

            import java.sql.*;

            public class connectURL {

                public static void main(String[] args) {


                    System.out.println("----------------------------------Start Connection---" + "\r\n");



                    // Create a variable for the connection string.
                    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver:LocalHost:1433;" +
                        "databaseName=stocksandshares;integratedSecurity=true;";

                    // Declare the JDBC objects.
                    Connection con = null;
                    Statement stmt = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;

                        try {
                            // Establish the connection.

                                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

                                // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
                                String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact";
                                stmt = con.createStatement();
                                rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                                // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                    System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
                                }
                        }

                    // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    finally {
                        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                            if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Can you paste it here so we can see what's the problem?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:LocalHost:1433;databaseName=stocksandshares;integratedSecurity=true;
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at connectURL.main(connectURL.java:48)

Comment: Where is 'the applications build folders'? Generally, `mssql-jdbc.jar` should be placed in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Hello - the application build folders are where all my java files are saved. In this case "Documents\JavaPrograms". I am not able to find a WEB-INF/lib directory anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is incorrect.

You missed the two forward slashes at the beginning.

Your connection string should be as follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://LocalHost:1433;databaseName=stocksandshares;integratedSecurity=true;
```

See [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url) that explain how to build the SQL Server connection string.

And do yourself a favour and start useing an IDE.

Comment: Hello - I have issues with installing IDE's on client machines, therefore have to do without it most of the time.  The connection string you suggest doesn't work either - I tried all the variations on the Microsoft documentation page.

Comment: @PB1 Then you likely don't have the driver on the classpath when running your application.

Comment: It perfectly works for me.  Can you paste the error you get with this connection string.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - I tried setting the CLASSPATH to point to the relevant directory in Environmental variables and using java -cp in the commandline.

Comment: @PB1 I suggest you update your question with the fixes suggested by this question, and exactly how you run your application. Most ways of executing java applications ignore the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.